# Searching for a book with a human survivor vs wolves/animals

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, animals

I'm searching for a book with a post-apocalyptic setting and a lone-human survivor conflict with wolves (primarily) and other semi/sentient animals.

It starts out that the reader thinks the wolves/animals are "bad guys," and at the end it switches and its the humans who were bad.

Trite, but was a good read. I believe it was published in the early 80s.

Comment: How sure you about the "bad guys" being wolves or animals? This actually sounds a lot like *I Am Legend*, which has vampire-like infected as the "bad guys", and was published earlier, but everything else pretty much matches.

Comment: Almost sounds like [*Heiro's Journey,*](http://www.amazon.com/Hieros-Journey-Sterling-E-Lanier/dp/0345308417) but there was never any question of the humans being the good guys.